# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected state READY actual state DEALLOCATED error when run CMUSphinx example

Tags: speech-recognition, speech, cmusphinx

I　have　run StreamSpeechRecognizer example from :http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4

but get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected state READY actual state       DEALLOCATED
at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.checkState(Recognizer.java:137)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.recognize(Recognizer.java:106)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.recognize(Recognizer.java:125)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.AbstractSpeechRecognizer.getResult(AbstractSpeechRecognizer.java:50)
at com.mbi.ciolab.vpa.speech.sphinx4.StreamSpeechRecognizerTest.main(StreamSpeechRecognizerTest.java:37)
```

The code as following :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    // Set path to acoustic model.
    //configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz");
    // Set path to dictionary.
    //configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz/dict/cmudict.0.6d");
    // Set language model.

    // Set path to acoustic model.
    configuration.setAcousticModelPath("models/acoustic/wsj_8kHz");
    // Set path to dictionary.
    configuration.setDictionaryPath("models/acoustic/wsj_8kHz/dict/cmudict.0.6d");
    configuration.setLanguageModelPath("models/language/en-us.lm.dmp");
    StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
    recognizer.startRecognition(new FileInputStream(new File("data/test.wav")));
    //recognizer.startRecognition(new FileInputStream(new File("speech.wav")));
    SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
    recognizer.stopRecognition();
    while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
        System.out.println(result.getHypothesis());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably provide the code you wrote. Most likely you stop the recognizer while you shouldn't do that.

Comment: So move last stopRecognition to the end and it should fix your problem. Try to understand what is going on there.